# Visual patch tool for Mac

Tags: macos, user-interface, diff, patch

On Windows, there is TortoiseMerge tool that's able to open patch files (the files produced by git patch / diff -u, etc...), and then act as a visual diff utility to select/edit the patch chunks.

On linux, I've heard kompare does this.

On Mac, I haven't find any tool for this, so do you know any ?

PS: I'm not looking for diff tool which require giving you 2 or 3 files as input (since the patch I'm editing might not be valid, I can't apply the patch on a temporary subset of the file and diff manually).

Comment: Just tested kompare on Linux, and it doesn't support editing the output files, like TortoiseMerge does

Answer (score 4):

You can use colordiff and pipe in the patch file. Not a GUI, but definitely way better than just trying to read the patch file.

`brew install colordiff
cat file.patch | colordiff | less -RS`

Worked well for my needs. More info here: http://www.markusbe.com/2009/12/how-to-read-a-patch-or-diff-and-understand-its-structure-to-apply-it-manually/

Answer (score 0):

The tool I work for (ECMerge), as a "preview patch" feature. It lets you apply a (reverse-)patch on the file and produce the other side just visually, or simply 'tell' if it applied succesfully as a whole. While producing the other side, it can paste to the clipboard what was rejected. It has the usual options for context limitations and displaced application. Patch files have syntax colouring.

Once you could apply the patch as you wanted, you have a 2-way merge view so you can make a selection of what you finally want to apply, save or produce patches.

This is not perfect but workable.

Comment: Have you used TortoiseMerge before? If yes, does this tool allow to open a patch file produced by git-format-patch (that is, a patch file for many files, with file deletion and creation, and binary files) like TortoiseMerge does on Windows ?

Comment: It will handle patches for many files, including deletion and creation. Unfortunately, it does not handle the binary patches yet.

Answer (score 0):

PatchViewer on Mac OS X (http://appledeveloper.com.au/products/patchviewer/) does part of what you are after (display patch files visually using whatever GUI diff tool you like), but it doesn't allow editing the patch file.

(Disclaimer: I am the author of PatchViewer.)

Comment: If only it allowed selecting/editing the hunks from (THEIRS/MINE/BASE), I would use it definitively.

Comment: The weird trial politic which obfuscate the variables for seeing the datas disgusted me.

Answer (score -1):

The [GitHub app for Mac](https://mac.github.com/) does this, and it doesn't necessarily have to be used with GitHub.

Comment: I couldn't manage to find an option anywhere to open a patch file

Comment: same here - wasn't able to figure out a way to open a patch file to display in a user-friendly, visual side-by-side fashion